# toggleClass on the same container and show different content with tabs effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I ran into this problem that if I toggleClass on the same container using different links trying to show different content it wont show the container on any second link right away. Basically it will close the container and then I would have to click the link once again in order to show the content. I am trying to achieve tabs effect using the same container and toggleClass and unfortunately I can't figure out of how to show the container right away on second link. I would appreciate any advice.

Here is a live example http://jsbin.com/eyEnEvEC/1/

and the entire code.

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display:none;
}


.show {
  display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="" id="link2">Link 2</a> 
<div class="container"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){

  $('#link1').click(function(){    
    $('.container').html('Test 1');
    $('.container').toggleClass('show');
        return false;
  });

  $('#link2').click(function(){    
    $('.container').html('Test 2');
    $('.container').toggleClass('show');
        return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: why are you not using 2 different containers?

Comment: no need to toggle class for a single div

Comment: @Era is it possible to do it with single container? if the answer is no I would also accept it...

Comment: @rynhe would you like to explain the solution of not doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="link1" data-status="inactive">Link 1</a>
<a href="" id="link2" data-status="inactive">Link 2</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $.fn.toggleContent = function(ahtml) {
    var cstatus =  $(this).attr("data-status");
    $("a[id^=link]").attr("data-status","inactive");
    if(cstatus == "inactive") {
      $('.container').html(ahtml).show(); 
      $(this).attr("data-status","active");
    }
    else {
      $('.container').html(ahtml).hide();  
      $(this).attr("data-status","inactive");
    }
    return false;
  };

  $('#link1').click(function(){    
    $(this).toggleContent('Test 1');    

  });

  $('#link2').click(function(){    
    $(this).toggleContent('Test 2'); 
  });

});
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/eyEnEvEC/9/edit

Comment: This is two containers solution. My question was about single container. Not possible?

Comment: almost but it wont hide it on double click if the user wants to close it what toggleClass does actually or slideToggle

Comment: much nicer, thank you for your effort. If there is no anyone else with better solution, I will be accepting this answer.